# nextjs render page's content twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my nextjs app, pages rendered twice and content is duplicated. e.g. if my page contains *hello* text, it renders two *hello* on browser.

This is my *_app.tsx*:

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const { pageLayoutProps = {} } = Component;

  const mainView = useMemo(() => <Component {...pageProps} />, [pageProps, pageLayoutProps]);

  return (
    <>
      <CacheProvider value={clientSideEmotionCache}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          {Utils.EnvUtils.isServer() ? (
            mainView
          ) : (
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              {mainView}
            </PersistGate>
          )}
        </ReduxProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

It seems, what rendered on server, will remain on client too.

Comment: Are you using strict mode? also your code does not have any `hello`

Comment: @TusharShahi strict mode is disable. `hello` is in page component. this is my `_app.tsx`